# Limit tcp download speed in Golang

Tags: sockets, go, tcp

I would like to be able to limit bandwidth of tcp connection in my code. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869858/limiting-bandwidth-of-http-get) question has some clues, but not exactly what I want. I have tried to hack src code of go standard lib (net/tcp package), using similar approach, but failed. 
My main idea is to somehow write data from syscall to internal buffer slowly, thus making OS to drop tcp packets.

Comment: Even if you read slowly from the local TCP buffer, the kernel can still fetch up to `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem` (third number is max buffer size in bytes) at a time. For a long-lived connection you can average it over time (buffer fills in a burst, consume slowly, buffer re-fills, etc). To really limit bandwidth you need to do it at the OS layer, not in Go. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28203/40168 .

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment, the easiest way is to do it at the OS level with wondershaper tool.
If you look at '[wondershaper](https://github.com/magnific0/wondershaper)' script, it uses '/sbin/tc' command from the '[iproute2](https://github.com/shemminger/iproute2)' package.
I understand that it is not exactly what you would like to do, but you can go at a lower level by executing 'tc' commands in your source code with os.exec().
Implementing your own "traffic control" algorithm is maybe too much work and not necessary for your goal.